# Install oracle 12c database in OS X Yosemite without Virtual Machine

Tags: mac, macos, oracle

Can we install **Oracle 12c** Database without using any Virtual Machine ? Currently I have installed it in *VMWare Fusion* but it is consuming a lot of power.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oracle Database 12c doesn't run on OS X, so I guess you'll have to stick to a VM running a supported OS (see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

VM appears to be the only solution currently. You can attempt to dual boot your OS with a linux distribution, and install Oracle on that. I have only been able to install the instant client to get the SQL Developer to work on my OS X.

So something like this:
/Library/Oracle/instantclient_11_2/network/admin/

on SQL Developer, you can then point the directory to the tnsnames.ora in this directory to get your connections..

Answer (score -2):

Use Crossover or Wineskin for OS X

Comment: 6 word answers are not enough. If you reccomend a program, put a detailed explanation and screenshots to using the program.

Comment: and they won't work for Oracle

Comment: I didnt work. sad